# Keras loss and accuracy not changing

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I am building a DNN with keras to classify between background or signal events (HEP). Nevertheless the loss and the accuracy are not changing.

I already tried changing the parameters on the optimizer, normalizing the data, changing the number of layers, neurons, epochs, initializing the weights, etc.

Here's the model:

```
epochs = 20
num_features = 2
num_classes = 2
batch_size = 32

# model
print("\n Building model...")
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(128, input_shape=(2,), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))

model.add(Dense(num_classes,activation=tf.nn.softmax))

print("\n Compiling model...")
opt = adam(lr=0.0001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=None, decay=0.0, 
      amsgrad=False)

# compile model
model.compile(
    loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
    optimizer=opt,
    metrics=['accuracy'])

print("\n Fitting model...")
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs = epochs, 
          batch_size = batch_size, validation_data = (x_test, y_test))
```

I'm expecting a change in the loss but it won't decrease from 0.69-ish.

The epochs report

```
 Building model...

 Compiling model...

 Fitting model...
Train on 18400 samples, validate on 4600 samples
Epoch 1/20
18400/18400 [==============================] - 1s 71us/step - loss: 0.6939 - acc: 0.4965 - val_loss: 0.6933 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 2/20
18400/18400 [==============================] - 1s 60us/step - loss: 0.6935 - acc: 0.5045 - val_loss: 0.6933 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 3/20
18400/18400 [==============================] - 1s 69us/step - loss: 0.6937 - acc: 0.4993 - val_loss: 0.6934 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 4/20
18400/18400 [==============================] - 1s 65us/step - loss: 0.6939 - acc: 0.4984 - val_loss: 0.6932 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 5/20
18400/18400 [==============================] - 1s 58us/step - loss: 0.6936 - acc: 0.5000 - val_loss: 0.6936 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 6/20
18400/18400 [==============================] - 1s 57us/step - loss: 0.6937 - acc: 0.4913 - val_loss: 0.6932 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 7/20
18400/18400 [==============================] - 1s 58us/step - loss: 0.6935 - acc: 0.5008 - val_loss: 0.6932 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 8/20
18400/18400 [==============================] - 1s 63us/step - loss: 0.6936 - acc: 0.5013 - val_loss: 0.6936 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 9/20
18400/18400 [==============================] - 1s 67us/step - loss: 0.6936 - acc: 0.4924 - val_loss: 0.6932 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 10/20
18400/18400 [==============================] - 1s 61us/step - loss: 0.6933 - acc: 0.5067 - val_loss: 0.6934 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 11/20
18400/18400 [==============================] - 1s 64us/step - loss: 0.6938 - acc: 0.4972 - val_loss: 0.6931 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 12/20
18400/18400 [==============================] - 1s 64us/step - loss: 0.6936 - acc: 0.4991 - val_loss: 0.6934 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 13/20
18400/18400 [==============================] - 1s 70us/step - loss: 0.6937 - acc: 0.4960 - val_loss: 0.6935 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 14/20
18400/18400 [==============================] - 1s 63us/step - loss: 0.6935 - acc: 0.4992 - val_loss: 0.6932 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 15/20
18400/18400 [==============================] - 1s 61us/step - loss: 0.6937 - acc: 0.4940 - val_loss: 0.6931 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 16/20
18400/18400 [==============================] - 1s 68us/step - loss: 0.6933 - acc: 0.5067 - val_loss: 0.6936 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 17/20
18400/18400 [==============================] - 1s 58us/step - loss: 0.6938 - acc: 0.4997 - val_loss: 0.6935 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 18/20
18400/18400 [==============================] - 1s 56us/step - loss: 0.6936 - acc: 0.4972 - val_loss: 0.6941 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 19/20
18400/18400 [==============================] - 1s 57us/step - loss: 0.6934 - acc: 0.5061 - val_loss: 0.6954 - val_acc: 0.5000
Epoch 20/20
18400/18400 [==============================] - 1s 58us/step - loss: 0.6936 - acc: 0.5037 - val_loss: 0.6939 - val_acc: 0.5000
```

Update: My data preparation contains this

```
np.random.shuffle(x_train)
np.random.shuffle(y_train)
np.random.shuffle(x_test)
np.random.shuffle(y_test)
```

And I'm thinking it's changing the class for each data point cause the shuffle is done separately.

Comment: Not easy to say without your data. Can you share the Epoch loss reports? If the problem is not in your dataset, you may be using a learning rate which is very small.

Comment: What format are your target values, i.e. if you are using categorial targets then loss should be "categorical_crossentropy".
Have a look at the bottom of this page to check if you are using the right loss function, https://keras.io/losses/

Comment: The classes are 0 for background and 1 for signal, so i'm using sparse_categorical.